# How to manage keybindings when we switch between usercontrols in a WPF window

Tags: wpf, binding, switch-statement, key

I have a parent window and in that window I have 3 usercontrols.

My parent window is some thing like this:

```
<Window>
    <Canvas>
        <local:usercontrol1 Visibility="Visible" Margin="0" />
        <local:usercontrol2 Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0" />
        <local:usercontrol3 Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

All of these usercontrols have keybindings. I change the visibility of the usercontrols when it needs to show. But keybindings are not working at all. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Adding some of your current code might really help others with finding the issue. As your question is written now, it seems a little too broad to figure out what might be causing your problem. Include some sample code and anything you've tried so far. The following page might help you with this: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Have you tried using a `Grid` instead of `Canvas` and see if this works? Another problem might be that the user control needs to get the keyboard focus. So when you change the visibility of a control, you could try and make it focused: `Focus()`